# SMB - Server never responds to Session Setup Request

Tags: networking, smb

I am having very strange network problems.  I am on a domain where a few servers are located on a different subnet.  I can ping these servers, dns look them up and remote desktop to them by IP-address.  I however cannot find them when using:

net view \server
or
Try to access them via windows explorer.

The person next to me who has an identical machine and is on the same subnet has no problems, as a matter of fact, I am the only one in a 50 person company having this problem!

This wouldn't be so much of a problem except for the fact that my machine cannot use web services located on these servers, neither via HTTP or NET.TCP.

After trying everything I can find on the internet and some more (added a new network card, reset policies, etc.) I finally got WireShark to see what is going on.  When doing net view \server I notice that the server never responds to "Session Setup Request" but it did respond to "Negotiate Protocol Request".  So what could possibly cause the server never to responde to the Session Setup Request?

[image: WireShark Capture]

Here is the server side capture (Not same session)

[image]

Comment: you are on 2 different networks 172.20 and 10.101, to join those networks there is a router, a posibility is that you can be block either by ip or mac address

Comment: Possibly, but why then did Negoatiate Protocol work, it uses the same IP addresses and same Ports.

Comment: I have noticed (using WireShark) that this happens when  my computer tries to send packages larger than about 1500 bytes.  Is that a known problem?

Comment: Are you using a VM? It may be something on the routing , try to sniff the network on the router side. If the packet is shown on your side it means that the packet was sent from your network interface

Comment: Thanks @EliadCohen, as you see above I did network sniffing and found that some packages where being lost.  I finally figured out why, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out what this was by comparing my tcpip registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters) with a machine that worked.  What I noticed is that I had the following 2 entries

```
EnablePMTUBHDetect  0
EnablePMTUDiscovery 1
```

but the other machine didn't.  By deleting these entries, everything started working!

This however is very strange because these happen to be the default values for there registry keys so I do not understand why having these entries cause such a problem.

Comment: Valur please read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/900926/recommended-tcp-ip-settings-for-wan-links-with-a-mtu-size-of-less-than).
These parameters are not trivial nor default, someone add these parameter to block attacks. 

BTW how did you find this solution?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't reply earlier my e-mail program put the Stackoverflow notification in Junk e-mail.  Yes this solved the problem but I only found it by trial and error, that is I compared my registry with an other computer that worked.  Tweeked mine until my computer started working too.